# Get Ember component's name

Tags: ember.js

If I call `Ember.inspect(component)`, I get a response like:

```
<app@component:my-component::ember1246>
```

This suggests that the component is aware of its own name (`my-component`). Is there a way to access just that name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ember.inspect()` calls the objects `toString()` which in turn calls some internal ember metal functions to derive the name.

There is however an internal property which people have been using to get the name:

```
this.__proto__._debugContainerKey
```

This outputs `component:my-component`, then you can just split on `:`. There's an issue which will create a public way of exposing object meta information which we'll be able to use in the future: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10742

Comment: Glad to hear a public method is underway.

Comment: .__proto_ is deprated, please use `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)._debugContainerKey` instead.

Comment: I would really like to have this: `Ember.Component.reopen({ classNames: ['this-component-name'] });`

Comment: This is something to look at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-component-class-name  - adds a thing-name`-component` by default though.

Answer (score 0):

This `regex` will do the trick:

```
//Returns a string with full name of component, like: <ProjectName@component:path/to/component-name::ember793>
let componentName = this.toString ();

//This regex will match the component and capture the latest part of component path.
let regex = componentName.match (/<[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+:(?:[a-z]+[\/])*([-a-z]+)::[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+>/); 

//The latest element of array is the component name.
console.log (regex[regex.length-1]); //component-name
```

See https://regex101.com/r/rX9bQ7/3 for full explanation about how this works.